# How can I update a numeric column with getting values from another nvarchar column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to copy one nvachar column data to another decimal column in the same table / sql server. But I am getting error like 'Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.'. Is there any way to fix query? Can you give me an idea? Thank you in advance..

```html
Update OFFER_REVIEW SET
SUM_NEW = (Select CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0),SUM) from OFFER_REVIEW b where OFFER_REVIEW.id = b.id)
```

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an edit of my original answer which takes into account your actual problem, which is that you seem to have *text* numeric data in some locale in which the thousands separator is dot, and the decimal separator is comma.  You may try using `TRY_PARSE` with a locale argument:

```
UPDATE OFFER_REVIEW
SET SUM_NEW = TRY_PARSE(SUM AS DECIMAL(18,0) USING 'El-GR');
```

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen. But unfortunately it didn't help me. My text data value like '1.000'. The code converting only 0 values.

Comment: You mentioned that my answer didn't help you, but what would help _me_ would be to find out if my query gave you an empty result set or not.

Comment: Thank you for your comment:) My code is UPDATE OFFER_REVIEW
SET SUM_NEW = CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), SUM)
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), SUM) IS NOT NULL. And for example it converting '1.000' text values to '1' decimal values. I would like to convert value as '1000'.

Comment: In your locale is the `.` in `1.000` a thousands separator?

Comment: Yes, we firstly recorded data as nvarchar. And we need to convert it. Or I have to input alldata manually:(

Comment: @RCeyda Try the updated answer, which should be working now.